# Starting a UIActivityIndicator after a delay on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to start my UIActivityIndicator only if the action take too much time:

```
    - (void) continueLaunch {

        //operations
        //.....
        [activityIndic stopAnimating];

    }

    //my current method
    - (void)lauchApplication {          
        [activityIndic startAnimating];
        [self performSelector:@selector(continueLaunch) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
    }   

    //what I want to do
    - (void)lauchApplication {
         if ([self performSelector:@selector(continueLaunch) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f]duration > 1 second){
              [activityIndic startAnimating];
         } 
    }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best aproach is to start the Indicator after the duration you want to wait, and if in some moment before that duration something happens, you can cancel it:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f]
```

And for cancel it (From Apple Doc):

> To cancel a queued message, use the
>   cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: or
>   cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object: method.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is this:

1. Create a timer
2. Launch a method **B** in another thread every X sec
3. In the method **B** check: if the method **A** is in progress AND timer is > Y time, then start animating your activity indicator.